# How to merge multiple dataframe rows into one by key?

Tags: python, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
key     columnA
1        1199
1        8674
2        8674
2        0183
2        3957
3        0183
3        3647
```

Expected result:

```
key      columnA
1       11998674
2       867401833957
3       01833647
```

Is there sth. that merges the rows by key while putting the different values in `columnA` together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['columnA'] = df['columnA'].astype(str)
```

#### method 1:

```
df.groupby('key').agg({'columnA': sum})
```

#### method 2:

```
df.groupby('key').agg({'columnA': "".join})
```

optionally, convert the column back to int.

if you want to add separators:

```
# assuming separator is ":"

df.groupby('key').agg({'columnA': ":".join})
```